# Subset pandas dataframe by values that are less than 80% of max value in each group. How?

Tags: python, pandas, filtering, grouping, subset

I have the following dataframe:

```
d = {'group': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a'],
'cum_sum': [1, 4, 3, 9, 15, 6, 3, 17, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I want to filter the whole dataframe to only keep the records in each group that have cum_sum less than maximum cum_sum x 0.8 in each group.

I tried to play around with lambda parameters and to filter this:

```
grouped = df.groupby('group')
grouped.filter(lambda x: x[x.cum_sum] <= x[x.cum_sum.max()])
```

But I simply have no idea where to actually start... Any ideas..?

**UPDATED ACCORDING TO COMMENTS!**

Comment: Plase give us sample data, not an image from it.

Comment: Sorry for that, I updated my post

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df['cum_sum'].lt(df.groupby('group')['cum_sum'].transform('max') * 0.8)]
print (df1)
  group  cum_sum
0     a        1
1     b        4
2     c        3
3     b        9
6     a        3
```

**Explanation**:

First use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `max` for Series with same size like original `DataFrame`:

```
print (df.groupby('group')['cum_sum'].transform('max'))
0     4
1    17
2     6
3    17
4    17
5     6
6     4
7    17
8     4
Name: cum_sum, dtype: int64
```

Multiple by constant:

```
print (df.groupby('group')['cum_sum'].transform('max') * 0.8)
0     3.2
1    13.6
2     4.8
3    13.6
4    13.6
5     4.8
6     3.2
7    13.6
8     3.2
Name: cum_sum, dtype: float64
```

Compare by [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) for `<`:

```
print (df['cum_sum'].lt(df.groupby('group')['cum_sum'].transform('max') * 0.8))
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
6     True
7    False
8    False
Name: cum_sum, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so elegant solution, but it works.

```
grouped = df.groupby('group').max()['cum_sum'].reset_index()
grouped.columns=['group','max_cum_sum']
df = df.merge(grouped)
df = df.loc[df['cum_sum'] <= df['max_cum_sum']*0.8]
```